# TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined - Angular Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I am trying to show a chart using angular chart. But I'm get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined
    at Object.i.Type.extend.initialize (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js:9:27506)
    at Object.e.Type (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js:9:9713)
    at Object.s (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js:9:12974)
    at e.(anonymous function) [as Bar] (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js:9:13316)

My code:

```
app.controller('graphController', ['$scope', '$kinvey','$location', function($scope, $kinvey, $location) {
$scope.popula = function(){ 
  var query = new $kinvey.Query();   
  query.equalTo('idColetor', 659238569);                          
  query.descending('tsmilliseconds').limit(7);
  var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('dataBase', query); 
  promise.then(function(response) {   
  arrayVelocidade = [];
  for(var j = response.length - 1; j >= 0 ; j--) {          
      arrayVelocidade.push(response[j].veloc);    
    }
  drawLineChart(arrayVelocidade);


});
};


function drawLineChart(arrayVelocidade){

  $scope.lineChartData = {
      labels: ["30", "25", "20", "15", "10", "05", "0"],
      datasets: [
      {
        label: "Velocidade",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: arrayVelocidade
      }
      ]
    };
    $scope.activeData = $scope.lineChartData;
}



}
]);
```

In the index page I called:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-angular-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/angular-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Any information would help. thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

angular-chart expects the input data to be in a certain format (it's not exactly the same as Chart.js). Try formatting your input data to look something like the sample at http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
});
```

Notice that `data` is just an array of arrays, not an object like in Chart.js and `labels` is a separate array.